# loopbackjs: location query specifying metric meters instead of miles

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, loopbackjs

I am doing my first project with loopbackjs.

I am creating a query for a location based proximity function ("near"). I found this great example, and following it, and especially installing it locally and look at the code I was able to already get my app doing the near query, which is great.
https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-api-geolocation/

However, the example uses miles as maxDistance parameter.

Is it possible to have it use **meters** instead?

I looked at the official docs and couldn't find anything. The MongoDB reference says it's using meters for maxDistance - which the strongloop default example app is not, because I tried using 500 and it returned everything, only using 0.31, which is the equivalent of 500m in miles, my values got filtered the way I need.

Answer (score 0):

`GeoPoint.distanceBetween(here, there, {type: 'meters'})`

See the `geoPoint.distanceTo(point, options)` section in the http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/GeoPoint+class for more info.

Comment: Good catch. That's the GeoPoint.distanceBetween() function. Can I add that type parameter to a "where($geo: { near:..." function as well?

Comment: Yes, you can pass a type as an option. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/geo.js#L252.

Comment: Sorry @superkhau but this code: `where: { location: {near: position, maxDistance: MAX_DISTANCE, {type: 'meters'} }` doesn't seem to work though, it says "Unexpected token {" for the bracket preceding `type`...apologies if I am not seeing something stupid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out.

```
where: { geo: { near: here, maxDistance: distance, unit: 'meters' }}
```